# Sync two users tables on email confirmation

Tags: asp.net, identityserver4

I'm working on a project created using Identity Server 4 for authentication, an API application that handles all the data and business logic and a client web app.

The IdentityServer project uses a different database for managing the users of the app and the API project has a copy of that table that gets synced with the one from IS when the user logs in.

The problem I'm facing is this:
When a user confirms his email the information is handled by IS but until his first login, the user appears to have his email unconfirmed in the API project.

How can I solve this without coupling the IS project to the API one?

Answer (score 0):

I see various way to handle this.

- Use messaging system to sync data (Users and it't update) between both the database.
- Access DBContext of API project into the IS to manage users.
- Or even simply have api to give updates to API project upon first login.

Comment: If I access the db context of the API project from the IS project or create an endpoint that updates the API db upon the first login then I'm coupling the projects together, which is exactly what I'm trying to avoid.